# How may I call a blade view in a custom Http Exception? (Laravel 7)

Tags: php, laravel, http, laravel-middleware, laravel-exceptions

I am looking to return a view from the HttpException that is triggered by my package's middleware, currently, it returns a static 403 exception and I'd like to change that to a custom view from the package.

I have attempted returning a view in the exception itself, however, that proved unfruitful due to a receiving a TypeError. `TypeError Return value of Username\Roles\Exceptions\InsufficientRoleException::forRoles() must be an instance of Username\Roles\Exceptions\InsufficientUsergroupException, instance of Illuminate\View\View returned`

Here's the block of code itself, if anybody knows a way that this can be done without modifying the `App\Exceptions\Hander.php` it would be amazing, as I'm trying to keep this within package code itself and to not make manual edits for each Laravel app.

```
<?php

namespace Username\Roles\Exceptions;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException;

class InsufficientUsergroupException extends HttpException
{
    private $requiredRoles = [];

    public static function forRoles(array $$roles): self
    {
        $permStr = implode(', ', $roles);

        $error = 'Insufficient permissions to access this page.';
        $exception = new static(403, $error, null, []);
        $exception->requiredRoles = $roles;

        //return $exception;

        return view('role::InsufficientRoleAccess')->with('role', $permStr);
    }
    
    public function getRequiredRoles): array
    {
        return $this->requiredRoles;
    }
}
```

Any support you can provide would be most appreciated! Thank you for reading this. :)

Comment: how about you remove the return type from that method or correct it? you defined it to return `self` but are returning a `View` object ... and `array $$roles` ?

Comment: Wouldnt it be easier to publish laravel errors blade template and customize the statics as you see fit?